# Action bar on Action back (Navigation Up) to custom activity?

Tags: android, menu

I have many activities in my application

in that I have Given this

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

to Go back to Home Page from other activities

like Below

[image]

If I press those three buttons all menus are working
this is my Option menu

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

```
int id = item.getItemId();

if (id == R.id.abc) {
    Intent mypIntent = new Intent(this, abc.class);
    startActivity(mypIntent);
    return true;
    }

else if (id == R.id.web) {
    Intent webIntent = new Intent(this, Web.class);
    startActivity(webIntent);
    return true;
}
else if (id == R.id.about) {
    Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(this, About.class);
    startActivity(aboutIntent);
    return true;
}
.
.
.
..

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Here There is no menu named `id == R.id.login` or `id == R.id.home` but its going to login few days back its gone to home activity

but If I press Back.. action back is redirect to Login page Inst-ed of Home

I have added a Login page for my application using shared preferences.. and it is now launcher activity..

Here In my Login activity on if once user is sign in it should it should redirect to Home activity on every time..
and its working fine..

But on action bar when I press arrow button it is redirecting to empty login page..
if I press cancel entire app is working .. my credentials are safe except this action bar..

**Update**

I have Given Intent also if Login credentials success redirect to Home activity on app start up it will check every time

every thing is as for fine except action back

how to fix this...

Comment: Y u have back button on HomeActivity?

Comment: there is no back button in home activity.. I have more other activities.. Like website about ect... in that action bar if I press back its redirecting to Login.. why not home... Before adding Login page  its going to home... but now its redirect to launcher i.e... Login..

Comment: wt's the min sdk of app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright make sure u do declare activities as below -

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Now in every activity add below code block-

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
// Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
case android.R.id.home:
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Update**
add a New class file to check login or not else use home as default.. and replace your new class as `launcher` in `Manifest`

Comment: Yes I have Given this at manifest.. few days back its worked fine.. but now its redirecting to launcher activity.. see my Updated question I want at Action bar back not options menu..

Comment: @Don't Be negative: well that the android button rt? and u get the onclick of it in onOptionItemSelected() so thats the eficient way to do it.

Comment: but I want for back button..not options button

Comment: @Don'tBenegative: well that the Actionbar Back button

Comment: @Don'tBenegative: aren't u finishing ur LoginActivity?

Comment: yes that action back button is redirecting to Login insted of Home

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101035/discussion-between-kevz-and-dont-be-negative).

Answer (score 0):

Just override this method.

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
        {
             Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Activity.class);/*your activity name*/
        startActivity(intent);
        }
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: its ok but I have given this `if (id == R.id.web1) {
            Intent webIntent = new Intent(this, Web.class);
            startActivity(webIntent);
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.about1) {
            Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(aboutIntent);
            return true;
        }`     I need at back arrow button,,

Comment: whatever activity you want to redirect to just replace Activity.class with your own class

Comment: you shouldn't be starting activity again coz its already on stack

Comment: you are giving menus not back button check my update question

Comment: once you declare "actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);" you can access the back button using the method i provided.